# Stuck at "Compiling..." in React

Tags: reactjs, compilation

I am using React version 16.13.1, Node version 11.0

After every 15-20 minutes of using `npm start`

- the terminal says **Compiling...**
- browser says **This site can’t be reached** after a long execution
- no changes to the code trigger re-compilation
- server became unresponsive
- Am getting stucked

To proceed further I have to

- terminate the process using Ctrl+c
- start again using `npm start`, which asks to start the process on different port

Regarding Solution to this problem,Some says:

- Updating to node 11.1 worked for them
- Downgrading from node 11 to 10 LTS worked for them
- Since CRA already works on Node 11.0.0, issue has been fixed on node 11.0 itself
- The process has to be terminated using a tool like htop

Can anyone explain why it is happening? And what could be the solution apart from node version changing?

Comment: Did you find an answer that worked?

Answer (score 0):

That may relate you ESLintPlugin set up of your webpack . Set `failOnError: false` may fix that problems .

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue changing one simple tag that was written on the short tag form:

From this:

```js
<LockOutlined />
```

To this:

```js
<LockOutlined></LockOutlined>
```